# how to store the contents of an xml file in mongodb with java

Tags: java, xml, mongodb

Currently I converted an xml contents to jsonobject but I did not get the result I wanted, is there a method to store the contents of an XML line by line  and not convert it directly into a jsonObject ?
for example if the xml document contains a list of people I'd like to convert it into list of people (in json ) to insert it documents by documents in mongodb.

Comment: read JSON object in to Strings,integers,doubles, etc.. and with those variables you can create your own xml file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I want to do the opposite , from the xml  get a json  documents  to store in base

Comment: do same as I mentioed for json but opposite :), just read xml file in a for loop and store informations in variables then write them into json object. It is really easy you sould google and I'm sure you will find the answer. If you won't find. I'll try to provide some links to help you

Comment: I actually do not know the contents of the files , I need to create a generic applicaiton that can transform any xml to json  and store it in mongo, I managed to convert the xml file with json object with :XML.toJSONObject(xml)

Comment: so you have XML object which you can just XML.toString(); and take a look at its pattern. So you can "know" what its inside.

Comment: yes I can , but i need to create an app that do it automatically, I will not be there to change the code every time they have a new xml file

Comment: İs there a pattern in xml files ? İf yes it will be really easy otherwise do not even try.

Comment: what do you mean by " pattern in xml files " ? structure?

Comment: Yes structure, so you can extract their data without any mistake

Comment: yes the xml files have a structure

Comment: to extract from XML file use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762881/how-to-extract-details-from-the-xml-files-using-java     and use this link to create jsonobjects   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html

Comment: Okey, thank you for your reply, I will look at these links